# Как реализовать калькулятор в своём приложении

Tags: php, python, математика, интерпретатор

Мне нужно реализовать калькулятор.
В написании вычислений присутствуют переменные и математические функции (cos, sin и т.д. и в них могут быть выражения). Переменные - это имена некоторых объектов из которых будет браться значение. Формулы вычислений должны записываться на естественном математическом языке.

Как я понимаю, мне нужно реализовать:

- синтаксический разбор и проверку (например, что бы выражения были
  корректны и скобочки закрывались);
- выполнения расчёта с подменой    переменных значениями объектов и
  обработкой ошибок.

К этому добавляется задача зависимости между такими формулами. Результат объект с именем и не должно быть зацикленности по переменным (работа с графами для определения зависимостей?). То есть одну формулу можно рассчитать после расчёта другой.

Я понимаю, что писать интерпретатор формул с нуля для этого всего дело долгое. Есть нечто из пакетов/библиотек/фреймвоков в php и python позволяющее реализовать задачу быстрее?

Comment: Вы хотите написать интерпретатор на PHP?

Comment: Не совсем интерпретатор. Проблема в том, что пользователь должен писать выражения на понятном ему простом языке. Использовать имена параметров, числа, простые операции и возможно некоторые мат функции.

Comment: Это и есть интерпретатор. В простейшем случае ограниченный одной строкой. Поглядите у меня в профиле, там ссылка на проект интерпретатора. Правда это не PHP, и не python, а С++. Можете попробовать вызвать его из python-а как С++ функцию.

Comment: Спасибо. Посмотрю.

Comment: В простейшем случае можно обойтись запуском примера ob.exe и передать ему сформированный из строки пользователя файл, который содержит нужное для интерпретации выражение. Вывод можно сделать PRINT-ом опять же в файл и потом распечатать результат из этого файла в окне Вашей программы. Правда, в таком варианте это будет работать только под Windows, так как сейчас пример ob.exe странслирован под Windows 32bit.

Comment: Это не решение для меня.